# Using Qtip for tool tip with knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, qtip

I need to provide a tool tip for a particular column in my table.
My View:

```
<table class="tbl" id="dash" data-bind="with: Plan">
      <thead>
        <tr class="tag close">
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="scrollContent" data-bind="foreach: Course">
        <tr>
          <td><i class="icon"></i></td>
          <td><a href="#" id="qtipselector_01" data-bind="text: Title"></a></td>
          <div id="TooltipContent_01" class="hidden">
            <a> Test Tool Tip</a>                 
          </div>
      </div>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

I have included jquery and jquery.qtip.js.

I have written a function to show the tool tip on mouse enter.

```
 $('#qtipselector_01').qtip({
    content: $('div#TooltipContent_01').html(),
    position: {
        my: 'left center'
    },
    show: 'mouseenter',
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 500,            
            when: {
                event: 'unfocus'
            }
        },
    style: {
        tip: {
          width: 20,
          height: 14,
        },
        width:280,
        height:100,    
        classes: 'qtipabc',        
    }
});
```

Main Page

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
<!--Template binding--><!-- This is where my view is getting binded--> 
<div id="Container" ua-app-id="topVm" data-bind='template: {name: pageModel, data: pageVM }'>                  
</div>
<script src="Scripts/abc.js"></script> <!--Place where .qtip is called-->
```

Its not working as of now.

Comment: When is your code (to create the qtip) running? If it's running before you `ko.applyBindings` then it won't work. The DOM elements you are trying to bind won't exist. Another problem is that you are using `id` inside of a `foreach`. This also won't work. If you do this, then every element will have the same `id`, which is a no-no. Either use a class, or use an `attr` binding to give them a unique id.

Comment: Regarding your first point:
I have included scripts in this order
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="Scripts/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
<div databind='template'>

<script src="Scripts/Custom.js"></script>

Custom.js has the script for binding tooltip.

Comment: What order? Show us where you call to `.qtip()` is with regards to where your call to `.applyBindings()` is.

Comment: Have edited my question to include that

Comment: Where's your ViewModel code? I don't even see where you are loading knockout.js.

Comment: The data bind template in the main div is binding the main view model and internally its binding many view model. That is huge chunk of code and that is why i didn't include it here. I have included here one of the view which has a qtip and giving the problem

Comment: Then try and break it down to a simple test case, maybe in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and post it.

Comment: I have created new fiddle example here : http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/mBpJB/3/

Comment: Aditya, unfortunately, you are not giving us enough visibility into your code to help.  The fiddle you linked above is one that I forked in another question of yours, and it works.  Can you now change this fiddle to demonstrate your error?  If you cannot then there must be something wrong in your real code.  The order in which JS is being brought in, the order in which bindings are evaluating, etc.  If you are not able to initialize a qtip then it looks like you are trying to initialize it before the qtip library has been included.

Comment: I have single page application which has a core framework which takes care of the knockout binding, and we use it in our project where i define the Views and the View model. Its a huge chunk of code and that is why i'm trying to create a scenario here. I understand the issue is with the way things are getting called, but not able to figure out where.

Comment: As shown in the question area(also this is they way it is getting loaded in chrome) Main page is first loading the Jquery and then Jquery Qtip and after that abc.js is called which has the Custom binding defined, after this all the templated are getting binded.
So custom binding is loaded before the ko.apply bindings.
I have tried calling it inside $('element').live('mouseover', function() and $('element').on('mouseover', function() still doesn't help

Comment: One thing you might want to try is to put your `qtip` initialization inside a `setTimeout`.  Sometimes, when using custom bindings to interact with a jQuery control you need to push the jQuery control initialization to the bottom of the JavaScript execution stack.  This gives Knockout time to fully evaluate observables and render the template before Qtip tries to bind to the element.  It's not needed in my simple example, but here is how it would look: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/mBpJB/4/

Comment: Thanks, i found the problem. It was occurring when it was getting loaded before foundation.min.js. I just kept it after that in the library sequence and it started working. Not sure yet what in foundation.min.js was causing the problem.

Comment: In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/mBpJB/3/ ....Can you show me how to add tool tip to each row, if tooltip content was coming from a separate html file. Also how will i pass Data to my tool tip. I'm trying to understand template binding here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#qtipselector_01').qtip({
    content: $('div#TooltipContent_01').html(),
    position: {
        my: 'left center'
    },
    show: 'mouseenter',
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 500,            
            when: {
                event: 'unfocus'
            }
        },
    style: {
        tip: {
          width: 20,
          height: 14
        },
        width:280,
        height:100,    
        classes: 'qtipabc'       
    }
});


});
```

You should place your qTip code within a $(document).ready block. Also, you have some extra commas in there that can interfere

Comment: When i put the same code inside document.ready it is giving error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input .

Also this works completely fine when used outside the template, i mean when i don't use template binding. So this problem is basically due to template binding and the script runs completely fine otherwise