# Qtip for tool tip with knockout giving Object [object Object] has no method 'qtip' error

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, qtip

I am getting a error when trying to call qtip method from my code:
Object [object Object] has no method 'qtip'  error

The problem is it works when not used without knockout template binding. But since i'm using that the qtip library loads before the actual content and that is creating a problem.
Tried Custom binding, when calling .qtip() method inside the init function, i'm still getting the same error.

Problem is $(element).qtip is null

```
ko.bindingHandlers.loadqtip = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            alert($(element).qtip==null); //This returns true
        }
```

Tried creating a fiddle example here: [jsfiddle.net/mBpJB](http://jsfiddle.net/mBpJB)

Using: knockout v2.1.0 , qTip2 v2.0.0, jQuery v1.8.2

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue with your fiddle was that you declared the custom knockout binding handler *after* you did the `ko.applyBindings`. Custom bindings should come before binding. You also had a double quote that was messing up the HTML formatting.

Here is a functioning fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/mBpJB/3/

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I created this just to test in fiddle. My actual problem is stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529460/using-qtip-for-tool-tip-with-knockout
Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong here. I'm stuck with this problem for 2 days.
As stated above in my actual code $(element).qtip is coming null.
I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'qtip'

Comment: jsfiddle.net/jearles/mBpJB/3 In this example i'm facing two problems. First when i'm trying to pass any data to tool tip its not working until and unless i put the div inside a <td>, in this case my table alignment is gone for a toss as it has one more column than header. Also it start working if i give a td tootl tip stops working. Also i'm not able to bind data to this tool tip properly....... Please find my edited version http://jsfiddle.net/adi85/mBpJB/8/